# How to count the elements in $GL_n(F_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

Here $F_p=\Bbb Z_p$ with $p$ prime, and $GL$ denotes general linear group.

The answer is 
$$|GL_n(F_p)|=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(p^n-p^k)$$
Amazing, but I have no idea how they got this!

Maybe it should go like this: first we fit $n$ elements arbitrarily into the first column but at least one of them is nonzero. So there are $p^n-1$ ways. Then we again fit $n$ elements into the second column so that it is not parallel to the first one, so there should be $p^n-p$ distinct arrangements, since any nonzero element in $F_p$ has exactly order $p$. But when it comes to the third column, I get lost.

So perhaps I need to know this, for $m$ independent vectors in $F_p^n$, the resulting subspace that they span contains exactly $p^n-p^m$ elements, is it true？If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: This is just a vector space of dimension $m$ over the field $F_p$ so it is in bijection with $F_p^m$

Comment: @Thomas Oh yes how I could've forgot this!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit: suppose we have already chosen $m$ LI elements of $F_p^n$. These, then, form a basis to a subspace isomorphic to $F_p^m$.

Now $|F_p^m| = p^m$. By the LI of the columns already chosen, none of the columns is the $0$-vector, so we obtain $p^m - 1$ possible linear combinations we can make from our choices of columns, which we must exclude from choosing to be the $m+1$-th column vector.

The $m+1$-th column cannot be the $0$-vector either, so among the non-zero $p^n - 1$ vectors we could possibly choose, only:

$(p^n - 1) - (p^m - 1) = p^n - p^m$ will make our first $m+1$ columns LI.